# Wildfly Docker Image vs Native Wildfly deployment

Tags: java, spring, docker, wildfly

I have a war application built around SpringFramework 5.3 and this deploys quite happily to a local installation of Wildfly 27 by copying to the deployments directory. There are no other changes required to the default installation of Wildfly.

I've been trying to build a docker image based on

> quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:27.0.0.Final-jdk17

I copy the same war file to the /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/ directory and the build is successful. However, when I run this image, I can see a large number of errors similar to the following:

```
Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in Module "deployment.****.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet (Module "deployment.****.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet (Module "deployment.****.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/HttpServletBean (Module "deployment.****.war" from Service Module Loader): javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
```

So a few questions:

Why does the the docker image behave differently?

Do I need to exclude some modules from the Wildfly docker deployment and if so, which ones?

Comment: What version of Wildfly were you using locally?  It looks like your code is still looking for Java EE 8 code - `javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet` specifically.  Wildfly 27 uses EE 10.

Comment: You'd need to use Spring 6.0 if you want to use WildFly 27+. As @stdunbar says, WildFly 27+ is a Jakarta EE 10 server. Spring 5.x targets Jakarta EE 8 while Spring 6.0 targets Jakarta EE 9+.

Comment: Thanks @stdunbar, You are correct. Looks like I've picked up an older version on my local path (i.e. Wildfly 26) but wildfly 27 for the docker image

Comment: Thanks @JamesR.Perkins. I have now completed and this now runs in Wildfly 27 locally